# Determining plane intersection with a ray

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I know the starting point $P$ and the direction vector $\vec{D}$ of a ray and, and I have a plane specified by a normal vector and a point in the plane $X$. under what conditions can I be certain the ray will intersect the plane? I believe it comes down to the sign of the dot product between $\vec{D}$ and some vector which specifies the plane, but I'm unsure of the specific details, nor how $P$ fits into this. Would someone kindly help me clear this up?

Answer (score 4):

The intersection $Q$ lies on the plane, which means
$$
\vec{N}\cdot Q = \vec{N}\cdot X
$$
and it is part of the ray, which means
$$
Q=P + \lambda \vec{D} \;\;\text{for some}\;\; \lambda \geq 0
$$
Now insert one into the other and you get
$$
\vec{N}\cdot P+\lambda\,\left(\vec{N}\cdot \vec{D}\right) = \vec{N}\cdot X
$$
or
$$
\lambda =\frac {\vec{N}\cdot (X-P)}{\vec{N}\cdot \vec{D}}
$$
If $\lambda$ is positive, then the intersection is on the ray. If it is negative, then the ray points away from the plane. If it is $0$, then your starting point is part of the plane.

If $\vec{N}\cdot \vec{D} = 0,$ then the ray lies on the plane (if $\vec{N}\cdot (X-P)=0$) or it is parallel to the plane with no intersection at all (if $\vec{N}\cdot (X-P)\neq 0$).

As you can see, you do not even have to calculate $\lambda.$ It is sufficient to know the signs of $\vec{N}\cdot (X-P)$ and $\vec{N}\cdot \vec{D}.$

**Edit**

Let $a = \vec{N}\cdot (X-P)$ and $b = \vec{N}\cdot \vec{D}$. Then
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 & a<0 & a=0 & a>0 \\
\hline 
b<0 & \text{ray points towards} & P \text{ on plane} &  \text{ray points away from} \\
 & \text{plane, intersection} &   &  \text{plane, no intersection} \\
\hline 
b=0 & \text{ray and plane parallel,} & \text{ray on plane} &  \text{ray and plane parallel,} \\
    & \text{no intersection} &  &  \text{no intersection} \\
\hline 
b>0 & \text{ray points away from}  &  P \text{ on plane} &  \text{ray points towards} \\
 & \text{plane, no intersection}  & &  \text{plane, intersection}
\end{array}

Comment: Why is it not sufficient to know only the sign of $\vec{N} \cdot \vec{D}$? Is it not true that if this quantity is $\leq 0$, the ray either points away from the plane or is parallel to the plane, and in either case can never intersect the plane? Why is it not that simple?

Comment: @mghanes404 Imagine you have a starting point $P$ of the ray on one side of the plane and a direction $\vec{D}$ of the ray that points towards the plane. Now you move the starting point of the ray to the other side of the plane, without changing the direction of the ray. The situation turns from "has intersection" to "does not have intersection" without a modification of $\vec{N}$ or $\vec{D}$, just by changing the location of the ray.

Comment: Likewise, you can move the plane without changing the direction of its normal. By doing this, you can obviously turn an "intersection scenario" into a "no intersection scenario". All this shows that $P$ and $X$ must occur somewhere in the formula.

Comment: So for instance let's say I know $\vec{N} \cdot (X - P)$ is $\leq 0$. Then For the plane and ray to not intersect, I would require $\vec{N} \cdot \vec{D} > 0$? so that $\lambda$ remains negative?

Comment: Be careful with "$<$" and "$\leq$". If $\vec{N}\cdot(X-P)=0,$ then $P$ is on the plane, and the direction of the ray is irrelevant. If $\vec{N}\cdot(X-P)<0,$ then you require $\vec{N}\cdot\vec{D}\geq 0$ for the plane and the ray to not intersect.